# Row binding results in R while maintaining columns labels

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I have a technical question in R:
how can I rowbind the following results (results1 and result2) into a data frame and keeping the columns labels for both:

result1:

```
meanAUC.SIM meanCmax.SIM meanTmax.SIM  AUC.OBS Cmax.OBS Tmax.OBS   PE.AUC  PE.Cmax  PE.Tmax
777.4444     74.64377     4.551254 820.7667 73.46508 3.089009 5.278274 1.604416 47.33703
```

result2:

```
 medianAUC.SIM medianCmax.SIM medianTmax.SIM AUC.OBS Cmax.OBS Tmax.OBS   PE.AUC  PE.Cmax PE.Tmax
764.6611        72.4534            4.5 795.765     68.2        3 3.908683 6.236657      50
```

The reason behind this is that I want to write them in a `*.csv` file in an organized way with the correct labeling.

Comment: Try: `plyr::rbind.fill(result1,result2)`

Comment: @ DatamineR Thank you. However, this doesn't exactly achieve the goal. it binds different columns into one row and fills similar columns names into a second row. What I actually want is to stack them together (i.e. to end up with a 4 row data frame; 2 for result1 and 2 for result2 stacked over each other)

Comment: You can achieve this creating a matrix, not a data frame

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the only reason you want to combine the data frames is to write them to a csv file, then you can instead just write each data frame separately to the same csv file. For example:

```
write.table(result1, "myfile.csv", row.names=FALSE, sep=",")

# If you want a blank row between them
cat("\n", file = "myfile.csv", append = TRUE)

write.table(result2, "myfile.csv", row.names=FALSE, sep=",", append=TRUE)
```

Here's what the file looks like:

[image]